# React Navigation v5 - Fire an action from sagas

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga, react-navigation-v5

i recently upgraded my code to react navigation v5 
before the react navigation was working just so smooth calling NavigationActions from the saga with no any issues.
now it's firing an action but never switch to the targeted screen through it's switching but only from the View Component like a button with onPress => navigation.navigate()

[image]

also the code responsible to fire the saga

[image]

after implementing the following :
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

i received this error

[image]

thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it's not navigating to the view (DesignerShow in that case)

Comment: now it receive such error after implementing navigationRef 

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/


The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet. This might happen if you don't have a navigator mounted

Comment: Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

actually i did not find a solution for this

but i made my own workaround, i will post it here just in case someone needed

in my HomeScreen i made the following

[image]

then for sure i added navigation to my global state

within my sagas i made the following

[image]